# angular - DOM .contains() cannot find element and parentNode is null

Tags: javascript, html, angular, element, contains

I think many here are familiar with the  `.contains()` function, that is used for checking whether an Element/Node is child of a parent Node.

Below is a simple Angular click-outside directive that uses the `.contains()`.

```
    constructor(private _elRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement) {
        const clickedInside = this._elRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(null);
        }
    }
```

This works great until when I clicked on any Image element, the `.contains()` actually does not find it & returns a `false` instead. Example:

```
<div id="parent">
    ...
    <button>
        <ng-container>
            <img id="child" src="...">
        </ng-container>
    </button>
    ...
</div>
```

Any idea why image elements doesn't get found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a HTML element is inside a `ng-container` block, that particular DOM element has its `parentNode` property as `null`. I suspect because the `ng-container` block will not be generated to DOM, so the reference to its parent node is broken.

This prevents the DOM `.contains()` function from working (because it is based on traversing through Node Tree)

I will report this issue at Angular GitHub.

Comment: I believe this is the difference between `@ViewContents` and `@ContentChildren`.

ViewChildren does'nt include elements that exist within the ng-content tag.

ContentChildren is only elements that exists within the ng-content tag.